# Method provided by component may need to be implemented, What does this mean?

Tags: object-oriented

I can't wrap my head around this statement:

> One common drawback of using composition instead of inheritance is that methods being provided by individual components may have to be implemented in the derived type, even if they are only forwarding methods

It's from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#Drawbacks).

Comment: In the future, I encourage you to use the Markdown "quote" feature (`>`) to indicate which part of your question is a quotation from some other source.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am also not entirely sure what it's saying, but to me, it sounds like this is saying that in inheritance, if e.g. the `Dog` class already has `function bark() { print('woof!')}`, then the person writing a `GoldenRetriever` class which inherits from `Dog` doesn't need to write a `bark` method since it's inherited from `Dog`.

On the other hand, if someone is writing a `GoldenRetriever` class that contains an instance of `Dog` inside each instance of `GoldenRetriever`, you will have to define `function bark() { this.dog.bark() }`.